# ListView can not return to other page. NameError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-listview

I have made ListView, it has "Try and Except block"

When it passes try block, it shows listview with SQL data.
but when it does not, I want to let the user go to another page (cancel.html).

Here is my code.

**view.py**

```
class DbList(ListView):
   
    def get(self, request):

        try:
            stripe_customer = StripeCustomer.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
            stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
            subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(stripe_customer.stripeSubscriptionId)
            print(subscription.status)    

            if subscription.status == "active":

                sql = 'select * from test_eu'
                msg = "abcdefg"
                sql += " where eng_discription ~ '.*" + msg +".*' ORDER BY image_amount DESC " 
                object_list = TestEu.objects.raw(sql)
                return object_list

        except:
            return render(request, 'cancel.html')
```

The error message is

> NameError
> name 'request' is not defined

So I tried to change the code

**return render(request, 'cancel.html')**

to

**return render(self.request, 'cancel.html')**

Then another error message occurred.

> TypeError  object of type
> 'HttpResponse' has no len()

How can I let the user go to another page in Listview??

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information.

Comment: The `get_queryset(...)` method supposed to return the `QuerySet`

Comment: This should be in `get` and not in `get_queryset`

Comment: @bdbd Thank you for answering.
I changed "get_queryset" to "get" but another error occured.
"TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

How should I write to make 1 argument?

Comment: Can you also show your updated changes here?

Comment: @bdbd I edited the code at view.py. Thank you.

Comment: Change `get(self)` to `get(self, request)` since it will always get a request object

Comment: @bdbd I changed get(self) to get(self, request) then I can see it renders to "cencel.html".
But when "try:" is fulfilled and returning "object_list" error occurred.

It says. Exception Type:AttributeError
Exception Value:'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'get'

Sorry to ask you alot. Please teach me what should I do?

Comment: I'm not totally sure with the error, but the main thing is this is a view and you need to return a response object. Not the raw sql's result directly.

Comment: @bdbd OK I got it, Thank you very much.